# In gradle custom plugin, how to insert a task between build and war?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'am creating a custom plugin and I need to execute the war task after another task has finished, but I could note get it to work.
Here are the task dependencies:

**`build`**: compile the java classes.

**`prepareFrontEnd`**: requiere build java classes as input so I added a `dependsOn build`, and create some files as a result.

**`buildFrontEnd`**: require the `prepareFrontEnd` files as input an create a directory structure with the compiled version of the frontEnd, so I added a `dependsOn prepareFrontEnd`

and finally

**`war`**: I need that this task add the output directories of `buildFrontEnd`, but if I add a `dependsOn` or `mustRunAfter` I get a

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:assemble
\--- :war
     \--- :buildFrontEnd
          \--- :prepareFrontEnd
               \--- :updatePom
                    \--- :build
                         \--- :assemble (*)
```

How could I solve this?

Here is the plugin [url](https://github.com/mdre/HGVaadinPlugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/github/mdre/hgvaadinplugin/HGVaadinPlugin.groovy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`build` usually is the end of the line and usually means `assemble` +
`check`.  And the `war` usually is part of `assemble`.  So you
have to integrate that way sooner.  For sure you don't want to have something depend on `build` - it's usually `build` (or rather `assemble`) depends on things.

I'd go: `classes <- buildFrontEnd <- prepareFrontEnd <- compileJava` to start conservatively.

Try how it looks with `gradle -m build` and adjust if needed.  Other options to chain into:

- `war`: most likely not correct, since the files might be useful while running the code in development
- `processResources`: usefull if you just generate some JS files that will be sent as static resources later

Comment: Thanks @cfrick. Now I must do that the war plugin collect the resources dir after it is generated an not at the config phase.

Comment: It work!! Thanks!!! I added a war{} clause in the project.config() and that do the trick.